# Eclipse Generic Text Editor Sort OUtline

Tags: eclipse, text-editor

I thought this would be very simple to achieve but I cannot sort the outline in alphabetical order in the generic text editor that is now the default editor for javascript files in Eclipse 2020-12. In fact I have no sorting options whatsoever in the outline.

[image]

This is all I have in any perspective using the generic text editor.

This really affects my productivity having to sroll through many functions in a javascript file to find the correct one. I have hundreds of javascript files with hundreds of functions each.

I am using Wild Web Developer tools as this is the way Eclipse is heading (and because each update automaticaly installs it). Also I have node.js installed even though I don't require node.js for anything other than the generic text editor.

I'd prefer to not have the overhead of uninstalling Wild Web Devleoper and installing JDT each time Eclipse updates. Ideally, I should be able to simply update when prompted and all works as previously.

This is the Eclipse version I am using
Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552

Does anybody have any idea how I can simply sort my functions and variables alphabetically in the generic text editor please? (I can sort the outline in java files

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/534 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/564503 .

Comment: Thanks nitind. So I known bug. I'll revert to JDST for the time being until it is fixed.

Comment: If you can vote or thumbs-up them, it's worth a shot. JSDT no longer provides a standalone JavaScript editor--WWD was really, really keen on being the solution for that.

Comment: OK. Just added my vote. You never know, it may help.